# systemd execstart python daemon dynamically using virtualenv from environment variable

Tags: python, virtualenv, systemd

I have Python script with works as a systemd daemon in CentOS 7. The daemon gets executed by the version of python I created in a virtualenv. I am trying to tweak the script to be able to set the virtualenv path in an environment variable so I can easily switch to a different virtualenv by changing paths via the one variable and restarting the service. I have created my systemd scripts to be able to initialize multiple instances of the daemon and this works great. When I try to use an environment variable to point to my python parser things break. Here is what I have so far.

/etc/systemd/system/pipeline-remove@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance %i
Requires=pipeline-remove.service
Before=pipeline-remove.service
BindsTo=pipeline-remove.service

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/python /pipeline/python/daemons/remove_tickets.py
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=pipeline-remove.service
```

/etc/systemd/system/pipeline-remove.service (to start all instances):

```
[Unit]
Description=manages pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /usr/bin/pipeline-remove-start.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

pipeline-remove-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start pipeline-remove@{1..2}
```

This works great for me, but things break when I try to set the python dir the following way:

/etc/profile.d/pipeline_envvars.sh:

```
PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV=/path/to/venv
```

/etc/systemd/system/pipeline-remove@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance %i
Requires=pipeline-remove.service
Before=pipeline-remove.service
BindsTo=pipeline-remove.service

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/pipeline_envvars.sh
ExecStart=/${PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /pipeline/python/daemons/remove_tickets.py
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=pipeline-remove.service
```

I then try to start it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart pipeline-remove@{1..1}
sudo systemctl status pipeline-remove@{1..1}
```

The status shows the following exit code 203 which means executable not found:

```
● pipeline-remove@1.service - pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance 1
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pipeline-remove@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-01-26 15:04:50 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 11716 ExecStart=/${PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /pipeline/python/daemons/remove_tickets.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11716 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 26 15:04:50 dev systemd[1]: pipeline-remove@1.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 26 15:04:50 dev systemd[1]: Unit pipeline-remove@1.service entered failed state.
Jan 26 15:04:50 dev systemd[1]: pipeline-remove@1.service failed.
```

Found the exec code [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#). Also found this in syslog, /var/log/messages:

```
Jan 26 15:07:13 dev systemd: Starting pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance 1...
Jan 26 15:07:13 dev systemd: Failed at step EXEC spawning /${PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python: No such file or directory
Jan 26 15:07:13 dev systemd: pipeline-remove@1.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 26 15:07:13 dev systemd: Unit pipeline-remove@1.service entered failed state.
Jan 26 15:07:13 dev systemd: pipeline-remove@1.service failed.
Jan 26 15:07:23 dev systemd: pipeline-remove@1.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 26 15:07:23 dev systemd: Started pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance 1.
```

When I try to drop the leading `/` in `ExecStart` I get a relative path error even though my env var does contain an absolute path:

```
Failed to start pipeline-remove@1.service: Unit is not loaded properly: 
Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status pipeline-remove@1.service' for 
details.
```

And status shows the following:

```
vagrant@dev:~$ sudo systemctl status pipeline-remove@{1..1}
● pipeline-remove@1.service - pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance 1
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 26 15:11:39 dev systemd[1]: pipeline-remove@1.service failed.
Jan 26 15:11:42 dev systemd[1]: Stopped pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance 1.
Jan 26 15:11:42 dev systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/pipeline-remove@.service:12] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ${PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /pipel...e_tickets.py
Jan 26 15:11:42 dev systemd[1]: pipeline-remove@1.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

I used [this](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html) guide to help me get started but now I'm stuck. How can I get my python daemon to come up while setting the python executable path from an environment variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more reading, I stumbled on the answer [here](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/systemd/systemd.service.5.en.html). The problem is the first argument of `ExecStart` must be a literal:

> ExecStart= Commands with their arguments that are executed when this
>   service is started. For each of the specified commands, the first
>   argument must be an absolute and literal path to an executable.

Reading on further on ExecStart it says:

> Variables whose value is not known at expansion time are treated as
>   empty strings. **Note that the first argument (i.e. the program to
>   execute) may not be a variable**.

I also ended up stumbling across this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199081/writing-a-systemd-unit-file-with-a-environment-set-executable-path) which looks like the same problem. In the end this is what worked: wrapping the entire thing with shell to run:

```
[Unit]
Description=pipeline remove tickets worker instances as a service, instance %i
Requires=pipeline-remove.service
Before=pipeline-remove.service
BindsTo=pipeline-remove.service

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/etc/profile.d/pipeline_envvars.sh
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${PIPELINE_VIRTUALENV}/bin/python /pipeline/python/daemons/remove_tickets.py'
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=pipeline-remove.service
```

So `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '<your command>'` saves the day, I can now specify the python interpreter path for my environment variable. Will leave the answer up, hopefully, saves others some time.